# How can I show two lasers in rviz (one of them in different position)?

Tags: laser, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am new on ROS and I am trying to display two lasers on ROS. I have been trying with tf with no results.
The problem is that I have the same origin for both, so the data of on is over the data of the other. I want to explain somehow that one of them is one meter to the left of the other.

Do you have any hint for doing this?

Now i am getting one laser data over the other, as you can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwk8718wykwzwd7/lasers.png

Thanks

Edit:
I am using this as launch file:

```
 <launch>
  <node pkg="sicktoolbox_wrapper2" name="lms5xx_110" type="sicklms_5xx">
  <remap from="scan" to="laser1" />
    <param name="ip_add" value="192.168.0.110" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="world" />
  </node>

  
  <node pkg="sicktoolbox_wrapper2" name="lms5xx_111" type="sicklms_5xx">
  <remap from="scan" to="laser2" />
    <param name="ip_add" value="192.168.0.111" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="world" />
  </node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 world laser1 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link2_broadcaster" args="4 0 0 0 0 0 world laser2 100" />
  
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183031/how-can-i-show-two-lasers-in-rviz-(one-of-them-in-different-position)?/) by [Rodolfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/17741/rodolfo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodolfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/17741/rodolfo/) on 2014-07-04**:
The problem is that I have the same origin for both, so the data of on is over the data of the other. I want to explain somehow that one of them is one meter to the left of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this modification of your launch file. Note that I've changed the frame IDs of the laser to match the frame IDs of the static transform broadcasters. You should be able to view both lasers relative to each other by setting your fixed frame in rviz to world.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="sicktoolbox_wrapper2" name="lms5xx_110" type="sicklms_5xx">
  <remap from="scan" to="laser1" />
    <param name="ip_add" value="192.168.0.110" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="laser1" />
  </node>


  <node pkg="sicktoolbox_wrapper2" name="lms5xx_111" type="sicklms_5xx">
  <remap from="scan" to="laser2" />
    <param name="ip_add" value="192.168.0.111" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="laser2" />
  </node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 world laser1 100" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link2_broadcaster" args="4 0 0 0 0 0 world laser2 100" />

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0